# No. of units sold column in admin products page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I can't seem to find any code online for adding a custom column in the products admin page (wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=product) to show the total number of units sold.

I just need a count of products sold for each product line on that page.

Forgive me if this code has already been posted here before, I couldn't think what to search Google for! :)

I used the code below but this shows the count on the public pages, I just need a count on the admin 'all products' page. Sorry if this makes no sense!

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'bbloomer_product_sold_count', 11 );

function bbloomer_product_sold_count() {
global $product;
$units_sold = $product-\>get_total_sales();
if ( $units_sold ) echo '<p>' . sprintf( \_\_( 'Units Sold: %s', 'woocommerce' ), $units_sold )              . '</p>';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to filter column then add the value to that column.

try out this code.

```
add_filter('manage_edit-product_columns', 'zillion_admin_products_visibility_column', 9999);

function zillion_admin_products_visibility_column($columns)
{
    $columns['products_sold'] = 'Total Sold Products';
    return $columns;
}

add_action('manage_product_posts_custom_column', 'zillion_admin_products_visibility_column_content', 10, 2);

function zillion_admin_products_visibility_column_content($column, $product_id)
{
    if ($column == 'products_sold') {
        $product = wc_get_product($product_id);
        echo $product->get_total_sales();
    }
}
```